# Prove that the equation: $x=\int_{0}^{x} \sin^4(t^2) dt%$ has only one solution .

Tags: calculus

prove that the equation: $$x=\int_{0}^{x} \sin^4(t^2) dt%$$

has only one solution and it exists at $x=0$.

Well, I thought about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but first I needed to find $F(x)$. I got confused about finding the $F(x)$ of $\sin^4(x^2)$ (which doesn't seem logical) or the $F(x)$ of $\sin^4(x)$ and then substitute $x=t^2$
well, going with the second option, I got that $F(x)= \frac{3}{8}x - \frac{\sin(2x)}{4} + \frac{\sin(4x)}{32}$  $ ->$ $F(t^2)= \frac{3}{8}t^2 - \frac{\sin(2t^2)}{4} + \frac{\sin(4t^2)}{32}$

I know that the function $\sin^4(t^2)$ is $continuous$ at $[0,\infty)$
then at each point in a closed interval $[0,b]$ s.t. $b>0$ and let $x_0 \in[0,b]$ we get : $$F^\prime(x_0)=f(x_0)$$

but how do I use this fact here? It seems that my intuition is in this direction but the overall image is blurred. I must be missing something. 
any kind of hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You have $F(x)=\int_0^x \sin(t^2)^4 dt$. You have $F(0)=0$, so the two are equal at zero. You also have $F'(x)=\sin(x^2)^4$. This is less than or equal to $1$, and is strictly less than $1$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of zero. That is, $F'(x)-1$ is nonpositive, and is strictly negative near $0$. Now notice that $F(x)-x=\int_0^x (F'(t)-1) dt$. Work with that.

Comment: are you implying that because the $F^\prime(t)-1$ is negative at a neighborhood of $x=0$ then In order to take the integral $\int_0^x (F'(t)-1) dt$ I need to multiply by minus one the right side and then by differentiating both sides I  get $F^\prime(x)=1$? thus $F(x)=x$?

Comment: @F1sargyan No. The point is that you have a function whose derivative is always either zero or negative, so $\int_0^x (F'(t)-1) dt$ is either negative or zero. It takes a little bit of work to check that it will actually be negative. But you do *not* get $F(x)=x$.

Answer (score 2):

$g(t)=1-\sin^4(t^2)$ is a non-negative function and a positive function in a right (or left) neighbourhood of the origin, hence
$$ \int_{0}^{x} g(t)\,dt = 0 $$
implies $x=0$.